# Something Large From Something Small

Tags: chess, construction

I have created a miniature chess puzzle that takes advantage of a piece of chess semantics that has some debate to it.

This is the puzzle:

> Construct a legal (meaning that two opposite colored Kings are required) chess position that has a combination of 7, no more and no less, pieces and pawns, that has **at least 54 checkmates in two** in total. It is up to you to decide the color and figure out the material distribution.
>
> Note that there must be no possible mates in one in the initial position.

To my knowledge, the solution that I made is unique, not counting the ability to mirror it and color switching. But I am not entirely sure, so that is why I stipulate **at the least.**

Additionally, can you identify what part of chess semantics that this puzzle takes advantage of?

Comment: *Exactly* 54 or *at least* 54? Does the position have to be reachable in an actual game? What's with the cut off sentence at the end?

Comment: Does a mate-in-one count, or does it have to be a mate in *exactly* 2?

Comment: What do you mean by "duals"? Do two mates count as different if their first moves are the same, but the second moves are different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I must be missing something because I'm getting a lot more than 54 mates-in-two for the position below? I have 116 listed, although I'm doing this by hand so there may be some errors included. Is there some rule I haven't considered?

> [image]
>
> ```
> Qa8 Kh8
>      Qd7#
>      Rf7#
>      Rg5#
>  Qc8 Kh8
>      Qd7#
>      Rf7#
>      Rg5#
>  Qe8 Kh8
>      Qd7#
>      Rf7#
>      Rg5#
>  Qb7+ Kg8
>      Qd8#
>      Re8#
>  Qb7+ Kh8
>      Qd8#
>      Re8#
>      Rf8#
>  Qc7+ Kg8
>      Qa8#
>      Qd8#
>      Re8#
>  Qc7+ Kh8
>      Qa8#
>      Qd8#
>      Re8#
>      Rf8#
>  Qcd7+ Kg8
>      Qa8#
>      Re8#
>  Qcd7+ Kh8
>      Qa8#
>      Re8#
>      Rf8#
>  Qd8 Kh8
>      Qb7#
>      Qcc7#
>      Qcd7#
>      Re7#
>      Rf7#
>  Qdd7+ Kg8
>      Qa8#
>      Qc8#
>      Re8#
>  Qdd7+ Kh8
>      Qa8#
>      Qc8#
>      Re8#
>      Rf8#
>  Qh5 Kg8
>      Rg6#
>      Qeg4#
>      Qg2#
>  Qdg5+ Kh7
>      Rh6#
>      Rh5#
>      Qh1#
>  Qdg5+ Kh8
>      Rh6#
>      Rh5#
>      Qh1#
>  Qdh1 Kg8
>      Rg6#
>      Qg4#
>      Qeg2#
>  Re8 Kh7
>      Qdd7#
>      Qe7#
>      Rf7#
>      Rg5#
>  Re7+ Kg8
>      Qa8#
>      Qc8#
>      Qd8#
>  Re7+ Kh8
>      Qa8#
>      Qc8#
>      Qd8#
>      Rf8#
>  Rg6+ Kh7
>      Rh5#
>      Qh4#
>      Qeh1#
>      Qdh1#
>  Rg6+ Kh8
>      Rh5#
>      Qh4#
>      Qeh1#
>      Qdh1#
>  Rh6 Kg8
>      Qg6#
>      Qeg4#
>      Qdg4#
>      Qg1#
>  Rg5+ Kf7
>      Rf6#
>      Qf5#
>      Qf4#
>      Qef3#
>      Qdf3#
>  Rg5+ Kf8
>      Rf6#
>      Qf5#
>      Qf4#
>      Qef3#
>      Qdf3#
>  Rg5+ Kh7
>      Rh6#
>      Qh4#
>      Qeh1#
>      Qdh1#
>  Rg5+ Kh8
>      Rh6#
>      Qh4#
>      Qeh1#
>      Qdh1#
>  Qeg4+ Kh7
>      Rh6#
>      Rh5#
>      Qch1#
>      Qdh1#
>  Qeg4+ Kh8
>      Rh6#
>      Rh5#
>      Qch1#
>      Qdh1#
>  Qh4 Kg8
>      Rg6#
>      Qcg2#
>      Qg4#
>      Qg1#
>  Qeg2+ Kh7
>      Rh6#
>      Rh5#
>      Qh5#
>      Qdh1#
>  Qeg2+ Kh8
>      Rh6#
>      Rh5#
>      Qh5#
>      Qdh1#
>  Qeh1 Kg8
>      Rg6#
>      Rg6#
>      Qcg2#
>      Qg4#
>      Qdg1#
> ```

Comment: Could probably squeeze in a few more by putting the Qe4 on f4 instead, but I'm not counting out all the variations since it looks like I'm still missing the point of the puzzle somehow...

Comment: @RewanDemontay "Chameleon questions" (i.e. changing the rules to invalidate existing answers), even accidental ones, are bad etiquette:  The most polite option here is probably to Accept jafe's answer, and create a new question with your "exactly 54 moves" criteria.  Possibly see if there are other criteria you can add to prevent "closed as too broad", such as "at least *n* pieces for each colour" or "*y* pawns"